# Equivalent of SQL ORDER BY in NSPredicate - CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

What would be the `NSPredicate` format equivalent to the following SQL query?

> SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1

I am trying this

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ORDER BY date LIMIT 1")
```

but the error is "Unable to parse the format string"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A predicate is used for filtering.  No filtering here, no predicate needed.

You want to sort your fetched results, which is handled by [`NSFetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/).

To order your results by date, descending

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
```

To limit your results

```
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
```